AirPrint printer not found on older devices (2.4 vs 5 GHz networks)
I have a fiber optic connection with a Huawei OptiXstar Wi-Fi 6 router, recently installed as an upgrade over the previous one (a FritzBox 7490).
My printer is a Canon i-Sensys LBP223DW which, until before this change, was always being recognised without any issue by all my (and my partner's) devices.
The line is configured with a 2.4 and a 5 GHz networks. All devices (an iPhone 6S+ & an iPhone XS; an iPad Pro 9.7 (2015), an iPad Air 2020, and an iPad Pro 2018; a Mac mini 2018 and a MacBook Pro M3 Max) connect flawlessly to both networks.
IoT devices (we have very few, a dehumidifier, a vacuum cleaner, and the printer) require 2.4 GHz networks—no idea if this is due to their age or other choices.
My workflow was to go to print a document, tap on Select Printer, and it would be there in the list waiting for me. Today, I noticed this was no longer the case. I reset the printer and reconfigured it from scratch, adding it to the local 2.4 GHz network. The printer's screen said connection was "Good", and the name of the network was correct. Yet, the MBP M3 Max with macOS 15.1 would see it (as it was configured before in Sonoma) with a yellow light. It would not print. I removed it and tried to add it again. macOS would not see it as before.
From the printer screen, I browsed to find its IP address, then, on macOS, added the printer through the IP tab, which worked. My iPhone XS (iOS 18.1) and iPad Pro (iPadOS 18.1) would not see it. I restarted the printer, then those devices would see the printer.
My partner's devices (iPhone on iOS 16.7, iPad Pro on iPadOS 16.7.10, iPad Air on iPadOS 17.6), though, would not find the printer unless they would switch their wifi connection to the 2.4 GHz as well, something that neither the Mac nor my other devices had to do.
I tried to restart the devices, to forget the networks and reconnect, nothing. If they are on the 5 GHz they would not find the printer.
Honestly, this looks like a stupid issue, but I have no idea how to work around it? Is it my new router doing something against specific devices which have an older internet protocol? Please notice that their connectivity is perfect though. Is it the printer?
What would you suggest me to do?
Thank you!

It would be up to the router to, well, route the traffic. Did you check the manual whether there are options which allow to influcuence this?

The router was installed by the ISP and I have no access to it. Should I call them to see if they messed up something?

If it worked before (with the Fritzbox) and doesn't now, then yes, looks like a router issue.

Technically, your router routes between four networks: The fiber, the LAN, the 2.4 GHz network and the 5 GHz network. In theory, all devices on LAN/2.4/5 should see each other. Airprint needs discovery to work, some routers may filter this by default.

The ISP checked, everything is fine on their end. Now, no device sees it here ... no idea what to do ...

Do the 2.4 and 5ghz networks have different SSID's?  Regarding devices on the 5ghz network not being able to find the printer on the 2.4ghz via Bonjour, since you know the IP address of the printer, does that IP address respond to a ping from a device on the 5ghz network?

Does the primer have Ethernet that could plug into the router? That has often worked for me

@MarcWilson: yes, the last two digits are different. The 2.4 GHz has :c8, the 5 GHz has :cc - can this be the issue? If so, what should I do or tell the ISP to do? What apparently solved it for me now was to 1) switch the Mac to the 2.4G, find the printer via Bonjour, add it 2) switch to 5G > printer goes offline in macOS > create new printer via IP > it works! So now I have 2 copies of the same printer in macOS.
SteveChambers: I have it, but it's way too short, I need 1.5-2m more. Besides, it has always worked before I updated to macOS 15.

That's the MAC, not the SSID.  They would have to have different MAC in order to exist.  Are they defined as different networks?  Unicast communication works between them, but Bonjour is not going to cross a broadcast domain boundary without a helper, which would point this squarely at the router replacement as the cause.

@MarcWilson: they are both formed by couples of digits, the MAC has 7 groups, the BSSID has 6. The two BBSID have the difference stated above. They are defined as different networks otherwise neither the printer nor other IoT devices would be able to connect. In origin, it was one network with two frequencies, but it had to be separated because of that.

I am sorry to once again post an answer to my question but the amount of trial and errors in these days has been so heavy that it is worth explaining what happened, and what I did to solve the issue.
The printer needed a dedicated 2.4 GHz network (hence the need to have the two frequencies separated and visible, with different BSSID and MAC numbers).
My Macs are usually connected to the 5 GHz network because of its increased performance. In that condition they do not see the printer. Switching them to the 2.4G one has the printer suddenly pop-up in the first tab of "Add Printer & Scanner" through Bonjour. Adding it there works flawlessly. Switching the Mac to the 5G network shows the printer as "Offline".
The idea of having to switch the Mac's network each time I needed to print was unacceptable, so I found the IP address of the printer, removed the previous printer and re-added it via the IP tab. It was immediately recognised, AirPrint v4 drivers were downloaded and, now, the printer was working perfectly well regardless of the network the Mac was connected to.
A victory? Yes, because things are now working, but I am not totally sure of why what I did was correct. Curiously enough, iOS and iPadOS devices detect the printer on their own without any help!
